# JQuery/Backbone remove not working in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

I'm testing a Backbone View in Jasmine. When I call the view's `remove` method, the element isn't actually removed.

I have this event handler in my view:

```
onModelChange: function() {
  this.$el.html('');
  this.render();
}
```

I have to have it written that way because manually setting the html is the only way to remove it. Calling remove doesn't do anything, and when the view renders itself again it just renders the new content appended to the old content. I even tried calling remove from the developer tools in Chromium but that didn't work either. However, remove does work when I manually test it in the browser, but it doesn't work in Jasmine and it's screwing up my tests.

Comment: Assuming your test isn't failing because you forgot to include the jQuery source, we're probably going to need a little more context. Toss up a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: @brianvaughn I think I was able to figure out what was happening. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to the problem lies in the jQuery source:

```
remove: function( selector, keepData /* Internal Use Only */ ) {
        var elem,
            elems = selector ? jQuery.filter( selector, this ) : this,
            i = 0;

        for ( ; (elem = elems[i]) != null; i++ ) {
            if ( !keepData && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                jQuery.cleanData( getAll( elem ) );
            }

            if ( elem.parentNode ) {
                if ( keepData && jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem ) ) {
                    setGlobalEval( getAll( elem, "script" ) );
                }
                elem.parentNode.removeChild( elem ); // right here to be specific
            }
        }

        return this;
    },
```

The remove function is relying on the node's parent to do the removing. I'm guessing that when the tests run in karma, the backbone view's node has no parent. To explore a bit more, I debugged the test. In the console, if I query for a view element's child and I remove it, it works.